# Rails 3 devise_for and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, sti

I have the following models:

```
User
Athlete < User
Coach < User
```

In my routes, I have the following:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations" }
```

I am wanting to create a route for each `sign_up` path (ie: /sign_up/coach, /sign_up/athlete)... should I create two different registration controllers or is there a way to do this with just one registration controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single registration controller doing something like this:

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

    def resource_class
      params[:type].present? ? params[:type].classify.constantize : super
    end

end
```

There are some other tweeks you would need to do. Whether that is worth it or not, I guess it depends on how similar the models actually are.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you create separate controllers for coach and athlete:

```
devise_for :coach, :controllers => { :registrations => "coach_registrations" }
devise_for :athlete, :controllers => { :registrations => "athlete_registrations" }

class CoachRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

end

class AthleteRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

end
```

Thanks.